# Updating value in DB throws java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

I'm struggling with this supposed SQL Syntax Error. I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

from this code at the line `statement.executeUpdate(("UPDATE tasks SET status = " + statusDescription + " WHERE Id = " + taskID));`:

```java
public void updateDB(String statusDescription, String taskID) {
    try {
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(statusDescription + " = statusDescription");
        System.out.println(taskID + "= taskID");
        statement.executeUpdate(("UPDATE tasks SET status = " + statusDescription + " WHERE Id = " + taskID));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sometimes I also get **this error** from the same code:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ea2ef485' in 'where clause'`

The important values at this point were "Done = statusDescription" and
"ea2ef485-0649-4e63-903b-e283b47dc8b0= taskID". But doing the query with those values afterwards in MySQL Workbench works fine. Just crashes in Eclipse

I tried running the SQL update statement in MySQL Workbench, and it works there (after I set ID to become the primary key in the Workbench. But it still doesnt work in Eclipse).
I tried googeling but didnt find any solution to my problem.
I also tried to add 2 more brackets to the sql statement, but it made no difference.
I tried putting '' around Id like this 'Id' but it didnt change anything.
Im quite at a loss at this point.

Any help will be hugely appreciated!

Comment: You should seriously consider *parameterising* your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the string separators, try with this code:

```
statement.executeUpdate(("UPDATE tasks SET status = '" + statusDescription + "' WHERE Id = " + taskID));
```

hope it helps, let me know

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! I added ' ' around both variables as you showed, now it works! 
Regarding my second error message, I was using UUID.randomUUID() to generate the Id, and I think sql had an issue with the - it contains. Now that I'm using a substring, the second error hasnt shown up again.